# unable to get near protocol transaction status via RPC

Tags: nearprotocol

Given a transaction https://explorer.near.org/transactions/JBb2DDe3i1CtBwESisLuhxXkWVZpCKYL4J1AdYwAQPsQ

When I query NEAR rpc:

```
http post https://rpc.mainnet.near.org jsonrpc=2.0 method=tx params:='["JBb2DDe3i1CtBwESisLuhxXkWVZpCKYL4J1AdYwAQPsQ","wasmgit.near"]' id=dontcare
```

Then I expect to get the transaction status

Instead I get the following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": -32000,
        "data": "Transaction JBb2DDe3i1CtBwESisLuhxXkWVZpCKYL4J1AdYwAQPsQ doesn't exist",
        "message": "Server error"
    },
    "id": "dontcare",
    "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> source: https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc#setup
>
> Querying historical data (older than 5 [epochs](https://docs.near.org/docs/concepts/epoch) or ~2.5 days), you may
> get responses that the data is not available anymore. In that case,
> archival RPC nodes will come to your rescue:
>
> - mainnet https://archival-rpc.mainnet.near.org
> - testnet https://archival-rpc.testnet.near.org
>
> You can see this interface defined in nearcore [here](https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/bf9ae4ce8c680d3408db1935ebd0ca24c4960884/chain/jsonrpc/client/src/lib.rs#L181).

via near-cli

```
near --nodeUrl https://archival-rpc.mainnet.near.org \
tx-status JBb2DDe3i1CtBwESisLuhxXkWVZpCKYL4J1AdYwAQPsQ \
--accountId wasmgit.near
```

via http

```
http post https://archival-rpc.mainnet.near.org \
jsonrpc=2.0 method=tx \
params:='["JBb2DDe3i1CtBwESisLuhxXkWVZpCKYL4J1AdYwAQPsQ","wasmgit.near"]' \
id=dontcare
```

Answer (score 1):

I, too, faced challenges in obtaining archival transactions at one point in time.

To access these transactions, I utilized their public Postgres SQL database, available at the following link: [Postgres SQL with near txs](https://docs.near.org/tools/indexer-for-explorer)

However, this solution is not suitable for production purposes, as the database frequently experienced downtime (at least a year ago) and occasionally suffered from excessively long timeouts (I can provide the query if needed).

In the end, I opted for [Cryptomation.com](https://www.cryptomation.com/blog/getting_transaction_in_near), a service analogous to Scan services but with support for the Near Network.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34041041)

Comment: Ok, thank you for advice, in will fix it on this week